# Cross origin error with QNetwork webassembly

Tags: qt, qt5, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to make a post/get call using QNetworkAccessManager in my c++ code which is exposed to webassembly using emscripten.

When the exposed function is compiled and loaded in Javascript, the requests are getting blocked due to cross-origin request.

I am running the local server from the folder that contains wasm, js and html files.

[Edited]: After some reading on CORS, I tried by adding additional header parameters to request:
`request.setRawHeader("Access-Control-Request-Origin", "*");`

But this also didn't work.

```cpp
QNetworkRequest request(this->server);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
request.setRawHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");    request.setRawHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");

// building the json and network request object
QByteArray byte_payload = QJsonDocument(payload).toJson();
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec();

std::cout << "Request completed" << std::endl;

QByteArray reponse = reply->readAll();
std::cout << reponse.toStdString() << std:: endl;
```

Could you let me know how to resolve this?

[image: Cross origin error on browser]

[Edited]:
I tried to enable the node server for cros by using `cors` package. This enables the first `OPTIONS` call to succeed but the actual `POST` call that happens is send with incorrect payload.

[image: OPTIONS]

[image: Post]

Comment: What server are you using ? you need to setup you server to enable Cross Origin

Comment: @PabloYaggi, I am using python http.server to server the html, wasm and js files locally. I have also tried using `http-server --cors` to enable CORS.

Comment: Probably you need to configure some policy, I'm not familiar with python, it looks related to the server not Qt side.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue ?

Comment: I got server configured to accept the request from different origin i.e. through wasm and it has solved the problem.